# Network Analysing of Online Video Stream

Tags: video-streaming, wireshark, mpeg-dash

I want play a video stream by web browser and capture the network by Wireshark or other tools. 
How can I found the video resolution of video and other information of video?

Comment: Do you have a HTTP or a HTTPS connection?

Comment: Thank you for your response. HTTP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the browser's tools.  In Chrome, go to `chrome://media-internals/` in a new tab.  You'll see all sorts of stats:

```
render_id: 1323
player_id: 30
origin_url: https://example.com
frame_url: https://example.com
frame_title: Example
url: blob:https://example.com
info: Selected GpuVideoDecoder for video decoding, config: codec: h264 format: 1 profile: h264 main coded size: [848,480] visible rect: [0,0,848,480] natural size: [848,480] has extra data? false encrypted? false rotation: 0°
pipeline_state: kSuspended
found_audio_stream: true
audio_codec_name: aac
found_video_stream: true
video_codec_name: h264
audio_dds: false
audio_decoder: FFmpegAudioDecoder
video_dds: false
video_decoder: GpuVideoDecoder
audio_buffering_state: BUFFERING_HAVE_ENOUGH
video_buffering_state: BUFFERING_HAVE_ENOUGH
height: 480
width: 848
pipeline_buffering_state: BUFFERING_HAVE_ENOUGH
duration: 39.50686
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. How can I fetch this logs automatically?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the video height and width as soon as the metadata for the video stream has loaded.

```js
var myVideo = document.getElementById("myVideoID");

myVideo.addEventListener( "loadedmetadata", function (e) {
    var vidWidth = this.videoWidth,
        vidHeight = this.videoHeight;
    //Use the info however you want here

}, false );
```

Comment: The script can simply be added to your page. Looking at your question again, I think maybe Brad's answer will give you all you need anyway.